# Cause of repeated characters on startup?

Tags: boot, 22.04, startup, plymouth

I have a Toshiba Satellite LA850D-12P running Ubuntu 22.04. About half the time the characters ^[[23~ appear repeatedly on startup. Sometimes they  are superimposed on the splash screens for Toshiba and Ubuntu. Usually they are superimposed on top of the startup messages 'starting xxxxxx... ' etc on the LHS of the screen, sometimes not. I find this behaviour slightly annoying and I as if there's any way of stopping it. The machine usually starts up OK.

Comment: Can not find that model in a search. What year was it made? An old machine might do that.

Comment: sorry, my typo, now corrected, thanks